# How to declare Function's bind method for TypeScript

Tags: mootools, typescript

I am trying to use Mootools together with TypeScript. Mootools, and some modern browsers support .bind method, which is polymorphic.

How can I properly declare this feature in a *.d.ts file, to be able to use constructs like [1,2].map(this.foo.bind(this)); ?

I know I can *avoid* such constructs by using lambdas, but sometimes I do not want to.

Perhaps there is a mootools.d.ts file somewhere which I could download instead of reinventing it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's lib.d.ts already defines the bind function's signature in the Function interface as follows:

```
bind(thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): Function;
```

I don't think there's any better way of doing it until generics get added to the language.

For the time being though, if you want to use bind and the recipient of the resulting function expects a specific signature, you're going to have to cast the function back to that signature:

```
var bfn : (p: number) => string;
bfn = <(p: number) => string> fn.bind(ctx);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a growing list of definition files being tracked [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398150).

As for generating methods pre-bound to their this pointer in TypeScript I've suggested two ways of doing this.  1) a simple base class I defined at the end of [this thread](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397774). and 2) a more advanced mixin & attribute system [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398391).

Comment: All of the links in this answer are dead.